# Track 404 error pages or How to monitor http header request's status made by the browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, firebug, http-status-code-404

I am developing a script that helps track 404 error pages (using JavaScript) at the client side. I searched for tutorials/ posts on the same but didn't find any helpful to me.

One post mentioned using curl (PHP) on the server side & redirect the user to a custom 404 page. But that doesn't address my problem (I want it at the client side).

This [page](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter14.html) mentions how to create an http object, open up a connection & detect its status in this way:

```
var request = makeHttpObject();
  request.open("GET", "your_url", true);
  request.send(null);
 ....
  if( request.status == 404 )
      print("404 error")
```

But over here we ourselves are making the http request & hence have access to the object. My aim is to detect any 404 page errors from the request send by the browser (due to user navigation).

Can we monitor the browser's http object for response statuses? How does Firebug's Network Analysis feature access the http headers? Can I replicate that in my script?

I have noticed that browser's Developer tool's Console gives a 404 error for missing pages as well as individual elements like images on that page.

These are the possible solutions I could imagine:

1. Monitor the response.status of every http request sent by the browser
2. Use Developer Tool's/Browser's Error Notification to track 404 errors using an "API" for extracting those error notifications of the tool (if it exists)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
function returnStatus(req, status) {
  //console.log(req);
  if(status == 404) {
    console.log("The url returned status code " + status);
  }
  else {
    console.log("success");
  }
}

function fetchStatus(address) {
 var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
 client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // in case of network errors this might not give reliable results
  if(this.readyState == 4)
   returnStatus(this, this.status);
 }
 client.open("HEAD", address);
 client.send();
}

fetchStatus("http://yoururl.com");
```